# How do I massage/change an RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I've been having problems with a Google News feed. Its `description` field contains a whole bunch of HTML along with the actual one sentence teaser of the news story. What language/technology do I need to learn/use to massage this feed into something prettier?

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: I'm working primarily with Drupal, so I'm thinking PHP. If I need to use/learn a little Python or other language, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo pipes might be what you could use http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/